# Array is affecting other array value C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, windows-8

```
static int[] scores = new int[100];
static int[] scorescopy;
public static int orderscores()
{
   scorescopy = scores;
    Array.Sort(scorescopy);
    int sortingtoolb = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get a copy of my initial array and then trying to sort that copy. However, when I use the Array.Sort() function, my first array keeps on being sorted as well, but I would like to preserve it. I tried taking away the new declaration on the scorescopy and that did not effect the result.

Also, is there a way to keep my unused variables within the array as null? (if I am not using all parts of it, I get a bunch of 0's in the beginning of the array).

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 on a system running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between reference types and value types, and specifically what this means for assignment. Chapter 1 of most C# books will cover this.

Comment: It was actually covered in Chapter 10 in my book... but since I had forgotten that it was called cloning, I failed to find the answer on my own through it and the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a pointer to the same array, you want a clone:

```
scorescopy = (int [])scores.Clone();
```

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes it is valid C#. Well apart from it should be a capital C on clone();

Comment: @ReedCopsey Then don't just say its invalid. Say what is wrong. Saying it is invalid implies it is totally incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely simple solution! I had forgotten about the clone function.

Answer (score 6):

An array, when assigned, only copies a reference to the same array in memory.  You need to actually copy the values for this to work:

```
public static int orderscores()
{
    scorescopy = scores.ToArray(); // Using LINQ to "cheat" and make the copy simple
    Array.Sort(scorescopy);
    int sortingtoolb = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can do this without LINQ via:

```
scorescopy = new int[scores.Length];
Array.Copy(scores, scorescopy, scores.Length);
//... rest of your code
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression `scorescopy = scores;` duplicate the handle to the array.

if you want to create a copy of the array items you should change that line to:
`scores.copyTo(scorescopy,0);`

You still need to make sure `scorecopy` has enough room to store the items.
so you also need this expression: `static int[] scorescopy = new int[scores.Length];`

and now your code should like this:

```
static int[] scores = new int[100];
static int[] scorescopy = new int[scores.Length];

public static int orderscores()
{
    scores.copyTo(scorescopy,0);
    Array.Sort(scorescopy);
    int sortingtoolb = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will raise an exception if `scorescopy` isn't allocated first.

Comment: true - will fix that asap :)